# get the invisible UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I used the code below to get an invisible UITableViewCell

```
NSIndexPath* path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
UITableViewCell *cell = [listTableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
```

path returns something, but cell returns nil.

It looks like the code above only can get the visible UITableViewCell.

Your comment welcome

Comment: The cell is actually deallocated, so you either store the whole cells as objects or relevant data to update state, which I believe you want to do.

Comment: Why do you need the cell?

Comment: There's no need to get an invisible cell since it doesn't exist. If you need the data, get it from your data model (which you should do for any row, not just invisible ones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrowatindexpath?language=objc) clearly say it needs to be visible.

> An object representing a cell of the table, or nil if the cell is not
>   visible or indexPath is out of range.

Also, you are initializing the index just like how you would intialize any other variable, which has nothing to do with it having to be a valid indexPath.